# Invert Regex Matches

Tags: .net, regex

How would I invert .NET regex matches?  I want to extract only the matched text, e.g. I want to extract all IMG tags from an HTML file, but only the image tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with inverting the Regexp. Just search for the relevant Text and put it in a group.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with David H.: Inversion would imply you *don't* want the matches, but rather the text surrounding the matches, in which case the Regex method Split() would work.  Here's what I mean:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Regex re = new Regex(@"\sthe\s", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    string text = "this is the text that the regex will use to process the answer";

    MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(text);
    foreach(Match m in matches)
    {
        Console.Write(m);
        Console.Write("\t");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    string[] split = re.Split(text);
    foreach (string s in split)
    {
        Console.Write(s);
        Console.Write("\t");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. Are you talking about [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)?